# Laravel 2FA Login with Microsoft Authenticator App

Tags: authentication, laravel-8

I use voyager for my website admin which is in laravel, and I want to implement Microsoft Authenticator for admin login, I have check many link but not getting proper solution, Can Some one please inform how can I implement Microsoft Authenticator with laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Laravel Fourtify](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/fortify)

It will allow you to create a custom 2FA system, you can link it with the Microsoft Authenticator app and use it as per your system requirement. Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Laravel [Fortify](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/fortify#two-factor-authentication) is the way to go. There is additional [documentation in Jetstream](https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/features/two-factor-authentication.html) about setting it up. Jetstream uses Fortify under the hood.

It can be configured to use any TOTP authenticator application and generates the QR Code and recovery codes as well. Myself and others I know have had some issues using the Google App as a "user/client", but in my experience so far MS's Auth-app has not given me any hassles.